# Which proof has took longest time to be verified?

Tags: soft-question, proof-verification

I read from a newspaper that Mochizuki's proof of the ABC conjecture has not been yet verified. Is this the hardest proof attempt being unverified over mathematics history in the sense that it has taken longer than any other proof to be verified? Well, I guess there are many ideas in mathematicians papers that has not ever been shown to anyone other that the author him/herself but what about those proofs that at least two professionals have read? I also read that when all finite simple groups were classified, the computation of Schur's coefficient of M22 were verified later than originally computed but I don't know how long the verification took.

Comment: Petersen and Wilhelm claimed in 2008 to prove a particular exotic seven sphere admits a metric of positive sectional curvature.  To my knowledge, this has not been verified.  Perhaps more troublesome, I don't know anyone who is even trying to verify it.

Comment: Classification of finite groups has not been done and probably never will be (at least that's what I seem to recall hearing from and expert). Classification of finite simple group is probably what you are thinking of

Comment: @JackYoon Oops. My blunder. Fixed.